# How to remap a bunch of directories in Ant?

Tags: ant

I have the following :

```
<dirset dir="../release">
    <include name="*/src/**"/>
</dirset>
```

But I want the "*/src" lobbed out. How is this done? I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with `<mapper/>` or `<pathconvert/>`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to add an exclude, i.e.:

```
<dirset dir="../release">
    <include name="*/src/**"/>
    <exclude name="*/src"/>
</dirset>
```

... or perhaps:

```
<dirset dir="../release" id="ds">
    <include name="*/src/**"/>
</dirset>
<pathconvert refid="ds" property="ds.prop">
    <mapper type="regexp" from=".*/src/(.*)" to="\1" />
</pathconvert>
```